# Mean of hour and min in pandas multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, multi-index

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import datetime
from pandas import DataFrame as df
import matplotlib
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import fxcmpy
import numpy as np


print(con.get_instruments())
symbols = con.get_instruments()

ticker = 'NGAS'
start = datetime.datetime(2015,1,1)
end = datetime.datetime.today()
data1= con.get_candles(ticker, period='m1', number=10000)

data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index, format ='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %S')
data['hour'] = data.index.hour
data['minute'] = data.index.minute
data.set_index(['hour', 'minute'], inplace=True)
```

This gives me the following output:

```
        bidopen bidclose    bidhigh bidlow  askopen askclose    askhigh asklow  tickqty
hour    minute                                  
10  52  2.2400  2.2395  2.2395  2.2390  2.2475  2.2470  2.2475  2.2470  3
53  2.2395  2.2415  2.2415  2.2395  2.2470  2.2490  2.2490  2.2475  8
54  2.2415  2.2415  2.2415  2.2410  2.2490  2.2490  2.2490  2.2485  4
56  2.2415  2.2415  2.2415  2.2415  2.2490  2.2490  2.2490  2.2490  2
57  2.2415  2.2410  2.2415  2.2400  2.2490  2.2485  2.2490  2.2480  8
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
21  39  2.3385  2.3385  2.3395  2.3380  2.3465  2.3460  2.3470  2.3460  10
41  2.3385  2.3375  2.3385  2.3370  2.3460  2.3460  2.3460  2.3460  4
42  2.3375  2.3365  2.3385  2.3360  2.3460  2.3440  2.3460  2.3440  10
43  2.3365  2.3375  2.3385  2.3360  2.3440  2.3450  2.3460  2.3440  15
44  2.3375  2.3365  2.3375  2.3360  2.3450  2.3445  2.3450  2.3440  5
10000 rows × 9 columns
```

What i want to do is, get the mean of `bidlow` in such a way that i get mean bid low for hour 1 min 1 mean `bidlow` to hour 21 min 44 in the same table. How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think here is best working with `DatetimeIndex` with function [`DataFrame.between_time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html):

```
data = con.get_candles(ticker, period='m1', number=10000)
data1= con.get_candles(ticker, period='m1', number=10000)

#already DatetimeIndex, so not necessary converting
#data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index, format ='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %S')
data['hour'] = data.index.hour
data['minute'] = data.index.minute

#print (data)
```

First filter between times:

```
data2 = data.between_time('01:01:00', '21:44:00').copy()
print (data2)
                     bidopen  bidclose  bidhigh  bidlow  askopen  askclose  \
date                                                                         
2019-12-10 10:52:00   2.2400    2.2395   2.2395  2.2390   2.2475    2.2470   
2019-12-10 10:53:00   2.2395    2.2415   2.2415  2.2395   2.2470    2.2490   
2019-12-10 10:54:00   2.2415    2.2415   2.2415  2.2410   2.2490    2.2490   
2019-12-10 10:56:00   2.2415    2.2415   2.2415  2.2415   2.2490    2.2490   
2019-12-10 10:57:00   2.2415    2.2410   2.2415  2.2400   2.2490    2.2485   
                     ...       ...      ...     ...      ...       ...   
2019-12-20 21:39:00   2.3385    2.3385   2.3395  2.3380   2.3465    2.3460   
2019-12-20 21:41:00   2.3385    2.3375   2.3385  2.3370   2.3460    2.3460   
2019-12-20 21:42:00   2.3375    2.3365   2.3385  2.3360   2.3460    2.3440   
2019-12-20 21:43:00   2.3365    2.3375   2.3385  2.3360   2.3440    2.3450   
2019-12-20 21:44:00   2.3375    2.3365   2.3375  2.3360   2.3450    2.3445   

                     askhigh  asklow  tickqty  hour  minute  
date                                                         
2019-12-10 10:52:00   2.2475  2.2470        3    10      52  
2019-12-10 10:53:00   2.2490  2.2475        8    10      53  
2019-12-10 10:54:00   2.2490  2.2485        4    10      54  
2019-12-10 10:56:00   2.2490  2.2490        2    10      56  
2019-12-10 10:57:00   2.2490  2.2480        8    10      57  
                     ...     ...      ...   ...     ...  
2019-12-20 21:39:00   2.3470  2.3460       10    21      39  
2019-12-20 21:41:00   2.3460  2.3460        4    21      41  
2019-12-20 21:42:00   2.3460  2.3440       10    21      42  
2019-12-20 21:43:00   2.3460  2.3440       15    21      43  
2019-12-20 21:44:00   2.3450  2.3440        5    21      44
```

And then aggregate `mean` per hours and minutes:

```
data3 = data2.groupby(['hour','minute'], as_index=False)['bidlow'].mean()
print (data3)
      hour  minute    bidlow
0        1       1  2.290750
1        1       2  2.316000
2        1       3  2.305071
3        1       4  2.304857
4        1       5  2.302125
   ...     ...       ...
1239    21      40  2.284167
1240    21      41  2.328000
1241    21      42  2.323400
1242    21      43  2.291100
1243    21      44  2.315786

[1244 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: I was hoping for something like mean of say hour 1 minute 1 for the last so many days. And so all the next entry would be hour 1 minute 2 mean over the last so many days and not the mean of all the entries! This will be the avarage of all the minutes and hours over the last few on that same time

Comment: @newcoder - not sure if understand, but I try to edit answer.

Comment: That what i wanted but as you will see that in the data received the first hour is `2019-12-10 10:52:00` hour 10 and min 52. But with using groupby it shows hour 1 min 1. Why is it not showing from hour 10 instead?

Comment: @newcoder - Because `groupby` by default sorting by grouped columns, here hours and minutes, for prevent is use `data3 = data2.groupby(['hour','minute'], as_index=False, sort=False)['bidlow'].mean()`